# Google Apps Script, running time-driven triggers sequentially

Tags: time, google-apps-script, triggers

I've got 3 functions I need to run overnight (when no one is using my spreadsheets). My constraints are

- function1 must finish before function2 starts, function2 must finish before function3 starts
- Each process, in a worse case scenario can take 90 to 120 seconds to finish

I know that each script has a max execution time of 6 minutes before the server terminates the thread. In my experience I've seen this happen usually around the 5 minute mark.

I'm not going to put all 3 function into a single function as the worst worst case scenario (3x 120 seconds) could have the server terminate the thread.

What I plan on doing is scheduling these functions one after the other overnight
[image]

My question is: Are these intervals 61 minutes or 60 mintutes? EG Is it possible for Function2 AND Function3 to begin execution at 01:00?

I guess I could schedule them to fire at 23:00-00:00, 01:00-02:00, and 03:00-04:00 I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't involve 5 hours (worst case) to finish.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create triggers as you require. You need not depend upon the menu based triggers.

For example, for your case you can do something like:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {


  // Trigger Function 1 everyday at 23:00.

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('Function 1')
      .timeBased()
      .everyDays(1)
      .atHour(23)
      .create();

 // Trigger Function 2 everyday at 1:00.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('Function 2')
      .timeBased()
      .everyDays(1)
      .atHour(1)
      .create();

// Trigger Function 3 everyday at 2:00.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('Function 3')
      .timeBased()
      .everyDays(1)
      .atHour(2)
      .create();
}
```

Please visit: [ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#methods) for more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks Br. Sayan.

I should have stated before, but I need this to be able to run when I'm not logged into my computer (eg on vacation, weekend) for some reason.

I've tried programmatic triggers before, but then I need them to exist inside a function and therefore need to call the owning function. I can call the owning function, createTimeDrivenTriggers() in the example above, but as soon as I leave for the week at some time the triggers stop firing

Comment: It has absolutely nothing to do with your being logged in or not! Whom do you expect to log into their account at 2 o'clock in the morning, to run their script? What is the error you're getting? What is the full code? Then we can see. Moreover, you just need to run the trigger function once. Once the triggers are set it should call automatically the functions at proper time.Also provide us your `Logger.log()` entries, if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger programmatically that will run at the exact given time as in [1]

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction').timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(11).create();
```

Run this code once and the trigger will be set up

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically